# How to refer to a specific anatomical structure with variation?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

How to refer to a specific anatomical structure with variation in the scientific context, say in an academic paper? I can think of: "In Figure 1, you can see the variant muscle running from..." or ""In Figure 1, you can see the variational muscle running from..." or variated or variating. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is standard in your field?

Comment: You seem to have already worked out how to do it. Be careful about scientific terms, though - the 'variant' terms can have special meaning.

Comment: Thank you both for the responses. Such usage seems to be avoided for some reason, in standard textbooks they always list or refer the variations as "variations" or "variants" in general and then explain particular examples just by saying muscle. I looked at the publications but it is hard to detect usages, since variant is a commonly used word and often times people use it not like "variant muscle" but like "variant pectoral muscle" assuming the variant is the right word.

Comment: In academic writing, the first and second persons (I, we, you) are usually avoided.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different ways of saying that something in medicine is not typical, running the scale from just alternate but unproblematic, to causing problems, and these terms need to It very much depends on the domain of medicine you're in.

- **variant**. There may be a naturally occurring distribution of types and anyone may be called a variant.
- **atypical** . This is the most bland, just pointing out that a phenomenon just may be less common (a common euphemism in psychiatry, eg 'neuroatypical' for being ASD).
- **anomalous** for when the difference is rarer. This might point to a problem, or it may just be a difference that causes no problems.
- **abnormal**, when the different structure may cause problems.

There may be set phrases, like 'anomalous coronary artery' which may be referred to as a any of the above terms.

The words given above are only suggestions, and the local domain may have other ways of saying it, so it is worth checking with that domain (via some document search).

Comment: Thank you very much Mitch, these are very useful words for future references. But I believe I mislead you and implied I ask a general medical term. I was actually asking a specifically anatomical term used as an adjective for the concept of "variations". "Variation" here is another anatomical term. I hope this gives a better explanation of what I am looking for. 
PS: An exaggerated example of anatomical variation could be having 3 hands instead of 2.

Comment: @UğurDinç Oh. Then maybe I misunderstood your specific example. But It's hard to tell because if you don't know the right word, how can you explain the word you meant, by using words? Are you searching for a word that goes with just 'muscle'? Or can it work for other kinds of anatomy? And what is special about this muscle? Is it different from the muscles nearby? Or is it different from the way other people have this muscle? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: I know the word "variation", it is very commonly used in anatomy. I just happened to need the adjective form of it. I will use it for a muscle, splenius capitis, normally it is "one stripe" but in a specimen it has a bifurcation and has two stripes. I hope this gives a better view. I tried to simplify the case as much as I could, sorry if I failed :)

Comment: @UğurDinç I can't be sure but maybe: "you can see the anomalous muscle running from..." ?

Comment: So are you looking for the adjective version of the noun 'variance'? Maybe find a synonym of variance' and then look for adjectives for _that_. Eg, 'difference' -> 'different' 'you can see the different muscle running from...'

Comment: Thank you for your help again, I feel bad when people are trying and I am not satisfied. "Variant" was my best choice too but in textbooks it is never used in its adjective form but rather noun form. "variants of the muscle" I guess it is too specific to ask here.